# Why is the episode titled “Ethon”?

Tags: title, stargate, stargate-sg1

Most of *Stargate SG-1*’s episode titles have a link to the subject of the episode, but I have never been able to work out this one.

As a name it means “strong”, but it’s not a meaning that jumps out at the viewer.

Is there some other connection I’ve missed, or is it that to a North American audience the meaning of the name and the link to a character would be more obvious?

There are a number of characters who display courage and strength of purpose in the episode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The episode features a battle for the *Prometheus* one of Earth's interplanetary spaceships.

The name *Ethon* (or Aethon) is from Greek mythology

> In Greek mythology, Ethon was the eagle that gnawed the liver of Prometheus — the name given to Earth’s interstellar battle cruiser on Stargate. [Gateworld](https://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s9/ethon/)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aethon)

> The eagle who tormented Prometheus, Aethon, was the child of the monsters Typhon and Echidna.In English, aithôn may be written Aethon, Aithon or Ethon.

Comment: Thank you. I knew the story, but not that the eagle has a name and I never thought of spelling like that.